# Does a Merkle tree have to be a perfect binary tree?

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, riak

If so, what's the reason?  I guess to keep it balanced?  But is that so critical for Merkle trees?

Answer (score 3):

It is not required, but it is less efficient if unbalanced. There are a couple of issues that could arise.

If your assumed range of the Merkle tree was too large so you e.g. had a tree

> ```
>  a
> / \
> b c
> \ /
> d e
> ```

then you are sending more hashes than you need (b and c are redundant).

Alternatively, if you got the range wrong so an end bucket contained a larger proportion of your key range, you would end up with a tree like this:

> ```
> a
>  \
>  b
>  /\
> c  d
> \  /\
>  e f g
> ```

Here, there are many more keys hashed to create g than the other buckets so it is more likely to be different.  Fixing the inconsistency will involve copying much more data than the other buckets.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I am reading Cassandra's source code of MerckleTree.  It says, "A MerkleTree is a full binary tree that represents a perfect binary tree of depth 'hashdepth'."  It does not explain why it is implemented as a perfect tree.  I am guessing it's just a simple way to achieve balanceness.  (Then it is safe to assume a more generic, n-ary balanced tree would achieve the same.)

Comment: In Cassandra you can always do this since you know the token range in advance and can safely assume the hash function is pretty even.